# Why does my DatePicker have no border graphics?

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker

[Way it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJPrp.png)

Hi.

I have been looking all day to try and find out why my DatePicker looks that way.

Sigh.... now i can not post my picture :/

My layout is nothing fancy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000">

<TimePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

    />

<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:padding="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You could use Android's DatePickerDialog and just do this programatically, without defining it in XML. Here is a snippet from a project of mine: https://github.com/AdamMc331/CashCaretaker/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/androidessence/cashcaretaker/fragments/DatePickerFragment.java

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the theme you have chosen for the activity.
Try changing it and your datepicker will be changed